# Swift: How to limit the numberOfItemInSection in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView used to display images downloaded from the Internet. I have an array used to store the data: `var post1: [Posts] = [Posts]()`. And in the

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return post1.count
    }
```

the `post1.count` is 4 for example, but I just want to show the first 3 of them, how should I do to limit the `numberOfItemInSection`? thanks.

Comment: What about `return min(3, post1.count)` ?

Comment: if you know exactly the 'count' is `equal` or more than `3` you can return `3`, or else check the `count` inside this method and if it is morthan `3` , then return `3`, else return `yourarray.count`

Comment: @MartinR this works, thanks. cause I am new to swift, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return post1.count > 3 ? 3 : post1.count
}
```

By the way, if you want to show the first 3 of post1,you should use another array(which has 3 Posts) as collectionView's dataSource.